# Need help in Excel Adding 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

i just want to add column 2 to column 1 if and only if column 2 has just 1 text character in its cell .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xlte.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IF( LEN(B2:B18)=1,  A2:A18 & " " & B2:B18,  A2:A18)
```

This will give you the following for A1:A5:

1. Brian B
2. David A
3. Terri D
4. John-Paul
5. Katie

I assume the idea is to do the combining ("concatenation" being the more proper term), then to use the resulting info in, say, a mail merge.

If you have a different need, perhaps to combine the first name and middle initials, I'd start in column D with something like:

```
=IF( LEN(B2:B18)=1,  C2:C18,  B2:B18)
```

which would collect ALL the last names into column D. You might then copy it and paste over the column C values using `Paste|Special|Values`.

Then replace column D's formula (it `SPILL`'s down to all the rows that seem to need it because I used ranges like "B2:B18" rather than just "B2" but if you don't have that, just use the cell address and copy down as needed) with the first formula putting together the first names and any middle initials (ignoring the last names in column B). Copy the result and paste it over column A (`Paste|Special|Values`) so now you have a column of first names and middle initials in A and last names only in column C. Delete column B to have a finished product.

Or just clear the contents of column B leaving it blank if you prefer (maybe you know, or worry, that something, somewhere, refers to column B and you don't mind it getting a blank, but you definitely don't want an `#ERROR!` instead. Even leave the current contents if not getting a blank would matter.

Naturally, you can just use, say, columns D&E or E&F, for the formulas and NOT overwrite the original material, if saving the original is of value, or just to be safe, so to speak.

So many options. But the way to do the work that makes whichever option you need work for you is in the formula/s above.